# DB2 view all tables and their information

Tags: sql, database, db2

Is there a statement that will let me view all the tables on a database, their respective column names, and any other pertinent data?

I imagine I have to query the system catalogs? I am new to DB2 and unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: An important concept on this site, before asking others to spend time solving your problem, and spending your own time waiting for a good answer, we ask that you show that you have tried to solve it on your own. If you realized you needed to look at the catalog, what did you do to try to find out how to do so?  The *first* logical thing would be to look in the reference.  If you don't understand then ask here if it's about a programming problem, or dba.stackexchange.com for database questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the database:

`db2 connect to <database-name>`

List all tables:

`db2 list tables for all`

To list all tables in selected schema, use:

`db2 list tables for schema <schema-name>`

To describe a table, type:

`db2 describe table <table-schema.table-name>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, the COLUMNS view

DB2 for i
select * from sysibm.columns
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm

DB2 for LUW
select * from syscat.columns
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html